# Redirect to a port number depending on the URL

Tags: node.js, apache, http, gitlab

My server has 3 websites :

- Gitlab running with Omnibus on port 80
- React.js application in a Docker on port 3001
- Jorani (php application) on Apache on port 8008

Since DNS can't handle the port number, how may I redirect to a port depending on the URL the user gives, for example :

- http://gitlab.domain.com => port 80
- http://react.domain.com => port 3001
- http://jorani.domain.com => port 8008

I saw some post about Proxy or reverse proxy but i'm not sure if it's the good way to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution I'm using :

I changed my gitlab port to 8900.
I changed my Apache port to 80.

I'm now using virtualhosts with Apache :

For CentOS 7 in /etc/httpd/sites-available/

gitlab.conf :

```
<VirtualHost gitlab.mydomain.intra:80 >
        ServerName gitlab.mydomain.intra
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8900/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8900/
</VirtualHost>
```

react.conf :

```
<VirtualHost react.mydomain.intra:80 >
        ServerName react.mydomain.intra
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
</VirtualHost>
```

jorani.conf :

```
<VirtualHost jorani.mydomain.intra:80 >
        ServerName jorani.mydomain.intra
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/jorani
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/jorani
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem : I can't manage to make it work for gitlab with SSL (gitlab.mydomain.intra => https://gitlab.mydomain.intra/). Will post the solution if I find it.

**EDIT :** 
Here is the solution for gitlab with https :

/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb :

```
external_url 'https://gitlab.mydomain.com/'
nginx['enable'] = true
nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
nginx['listen_addresses'] = ['localhost']
nginx['listen_port'] = 8888
nginx['listen_https'] = false
```

/etc/httpd/sites-available/gitlab.conf

```
<VirtualHost gitlab.mydomain.intra:80>
    ServerName gitlab.mydomain.intra
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/gitlab.mydomain.intra/error.log
    Redirect 301 / https://gitlab.mydomain.intra/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost gitlab.mydomain.intra:443>
    ServerName gitlab.mydomain.intra
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/gitlab.mydomain.intra/error.log
    RequestHeader set Host "gitlab.mydomain.intra"
    #RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Ssl on
    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-For %<span class="pl-s1"><span class="pl-pse">{</span>REMOTE_ADDR<span class="pl-$
    #RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.intra.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/gitlab/ssl/gitlab.mydomain.intra.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the publicly-accessible internet, HTTP traffic should be over port 80 (or over TLS that runs on port 443 for HTTPS). You *can theoretically* have HTTP on any port, but that is **very** bug-prone and not all machines support that, so it's discouraged in production. As such you should not redirect traffic from `subdomain.domain.extension` to `domain.extension:port`.

Instead, you have two solutions:

**The three servers run behind three IPs**: each subdomain has an IP address. Each server runs behind its own IP. Your DNS server should send records for each of these domain name - IP address associations.

**Reverse proxy**: each subdomain goes to the same IP. Behind this IP runs a fourth server - the proxy. Its simple task is to look at the subdomain in the path and re-route the HTTP(S) traffic to the corresponding applications that it is connected to (gitlab, react, or jorani). Note that none of these three applications are directly accessible from the public internet.

Comment: Actually, it is not for the publicly-accessible internet but for the intranet. I will use the Reverse proxy method because i'm out of VM for now. Is Squid proxy a good one for this kind of usage?

Comment: Squid is used for caching, it is not the intended use here. Why don't you code yourself a simple NodeJS proxy in a few lines?

Comment: I didn't know it was possible. I will check this solution. If the user types "gitlab.domain.com" is it possible to redirect him to "https://gitlab.domain.com:80/" with this solution?